# Pagination with JPQL and BooleanExpression

Tags: java, rest, pagination, jpql, querydsl

I am new to pagination, I want to paginate my JPQL query, but i am not able to do that, please find below classes:

Service:

```
public List<Company> getCompanies(BooleanExpression predicate, Pageable pageRequest){
    return companyRepositoryImpl.getCompany(predicate, pageRequest);
}
```

Repository:
@Repository
public class CompanyRepositoryImpl{

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

public <T> List<T> getCompany(BooleanExpression finalExpression, Pageable pageRequest) {

    int pageNumber = pageRequest.getPageNumber();
    int pageSize = pageRequest.getPageSize();
    long pageOffset = pageRequest.getOffset();
    Sort sortValue = pageRequest.getSort();
//  String str = sortValue.toString();



    QCompany comp = QCompany.company;
    QCompanyAddress qCompanyAddress = QCompanyAddress.companyAddress;
    final JPQLQuery<QCompany> jpqlQuery = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
    OrderSpecifier<?> o = qCompanyAddress.addressLine1.desc();
    JPQLQuery<QCompany> query = jpqlQuery.from(comp).leftJoin(qCompanyAddress)
                                                    .on(comp.id.eq(qCompanyAddress.company.id)
                                                    .and(qCompanyAddress.statusActiveSwitch.eq(SwitchEnum.Y))
                                                    .and(qCompanyAddress.addressType.addressTypeCode.eq("1")))
                                                    .where(finalExpression).orderBy(o).limit(20);

    QueryResults<QCompany> fetchResults = query.fetchResults();
    List<QCompany> results = fetchResults.getResults();
    fetchResults.getTotal();
    return (List<T>) results;

}
```

In repository i have pageable object, but i don't know how to use it with JPQL. any help is appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

To load data as per defined `pageable` object, you have to remove `limit(20)` from you `query` definition. Then, you can do the following things:

```
List<Company> companies = getQuerydsl()
            .applyPagination(pageable, query)
            .fetch();
```

And you can return the list.

If you want to return Page instead of list, then you have to change a bit like -

```
long total = query.fetchCount();
List<Company> companies = getQuerydsl()
            .applyPagination(pageable, query)
            .fetch();
return new PageImpl<>(companies, pageable, total);
```

I hope, this will help you.